# Terraform Enterprise automation installation

Tags: docker, terraform, terraform-enterprise

While installing private terraform enterprise using terraform, I am facing this issue.
An issue was also raise [here](https://github.com/lemurheavy/coveralls-public/issues/1211)

After installing it, I get an error bringing up the browser 
`https://(IP):8800/initializing?redirect=/`

```
My machine type is ubuntu, image - ubuntu-os-cloud/ubuntu-1604-lts
```

"Error while initializing daemon: Error cannot GET /api/v

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing and configuring Terraform Enterprise, make sure you have a read of the [HashiCorp Terraform Enterprise Documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/enterprise/index.html)

[Here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/enterprise/install/automating-the-installer.html) is the steps for the Automated Installation

Most often issues within the daemon happen when all of the required steps aren't performed correctly.

HashiCorp also provides example repositories on how you can perform this installation on multiple clouds:

- [Azure](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/hashicorp/terraform-enterprise/azurerm/0.1.0)
- [AWS](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/hashicorp/terraform-enterprise/aws/0.1.1)
- [GCP](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/hashicorp/terraform-enterprise/google/0.1.1)

The Terraform Registry is a great resource to look for working examples that are used around the world and endorsed by HashiCorp and the Community:
https://registry.terraform.io/

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you skip some step in between, for example, I had to write license key, but I skipped that step and due to that all the docker didn't got internalized.

Comment: Are you able to close the question? or would you like me to create an answer so that it can be closed and help others?

Comment: @LachieWhite ya you can go ahead and create a better answer